# X could be manipulated and Y [could be?] compromised

Tags: grammaticality

The sentence in question is:

> It is highly improbable that a typical user would understand all the
>   potentially invasive ways in which their data could be manipulated,
>   and their autonomy compromised.

The alternate way of writing this would be to say 'and their autonomy could be compromised'. Stylistically, I prefer the shorter version but I'm unsure as to whether grammatically it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorter version is fine, but leave out the comma—to make it clear that "could be" applies both to "manipulated" and to "compromised".

Comment: It certainly is fine; I think it's more elegant to leave out the second "could".